# How to fit three elements in a div?

Tags: html, css

The input boxes should have good distance between them and the search button should be below them in the same div. As you can see, the placement of these components is totally messed up. Can you please tell me what's going wrong?

[image: those two input boxes]

```css
#A_1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(55, 160, 0);
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: -1px;
  right: 5px;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 228.469px;
  perspective-origin: 114.234px 21px;
  transform-origin: 114.234px 21px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 2px solid rgb(224, 224, 224);
  border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  font: 15px Segoe UI, sans-serif;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(55, 160, 0) none 0px;
  padding: 8px 38px;
}

#A_2 {
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(55, 160, 0);
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: -1px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 228.469px;
  perspective-origin: 114.234px 21px;
  transform-origin: 114.234px 21px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 2px solid rgb(224, 224, 224);
  border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  font: 15px Segoe UI, sans-serif;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(55, 160, 0) none 0px;
  padding: 8px 38px;
}

#title {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  font: 40px Segoe UI, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px 38px;
  color: rgb(55, 160, 0);
}

.tag {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 400px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #9dca70;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#INPUT_1 {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
  height: 40px;
  width: 285px;
  perspective-origin: 142.5px 20px;
  transform-origin: 142.5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224);
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  font: 15px Segoe UI, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(73, 73, 73) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#INPUT_1:focus {
  border-color: #9ecaed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #cc2631;
}

#INPUT_2 {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
  height: 40px;
  width: 285px;
  perspective-origin: 142.5px 20px;
  transform-origin: 142.5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224);
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  font: 15px Segoe UI, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(73, 73, 73) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#INPUT_2:focus {
  border-color: #9ecaed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #cc2631;
}

#A_7 {
  margin-top: 165px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 161.438px;
  perspective-origin: 80.7188px 20px;
  transform-origin: 80.7188px 20px;
  background: rgb(55, 160, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgb(55, 160, 0);
  border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  font: normal normal 600 normal 14px / 20px Gotham;
  margin: 150px 442px 0px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  padding: 9px 39px;
}
/*#A_1*/
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Hire Snapper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="looks.css">
</head>


<div style="height: 100px;">
</div>

<div class="tag" style="height: 206px;">
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Location" maxlength="100" id="INPUT_1" />

  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Specification" maxlength="100" id="INPUT_2" />

  <button id="A_7">SEARCH</button style="height: 25px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot going on here so please look through this fiddle to see all the changes: https://jsfiddle.net/u64wosb3/

The big things are:

1. Remove all inline style tags and apply styles through CSS
2. I surrounded the inputs in their own parent container and the button inside its own parent container
3. The inputs are inside a `display: flex` container and they have the property `flex-grow: 1` so they both take up the same amount of space
4. I removed your `display: inline-block` anywhere
5. Removed your extremely large margins
6. Removed that style attribute that was inside the closing tag of your button (not allowed)

Please comment if you have any questions. This will work for larger screen sizes, I did not want to mess with the large amount of styles you have.